# How to use 'let' (and supported ECMAScript 6 features) in both Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

ES6 script using `let` runs as expected in latest Chrome stable if it's inside a `"use strict"` definition. And it runs fine in Firefox if it is loaded using a script tag with the special type:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7" src=""></script>
```

*But* files with that special type now won't run in Chrome! In Chrome no script runs: silent failure, no console messages. What is the cross-browser solution? (I want to know if this can be done without transpiling.)

Comment: How about detecting the browser using a relevant feature test and then inserting the right `<script>` tag dynamically?

Comment: `let`, fat arrows, template strings, all work in CH+FF in regular script tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naïve solution, assuming you have control over the script itself, is to set some global within the script and check if it exists later. Iff it doesn't, replace this script element with one without the special MIME type so it can run on other browsers. The global can safely be ignored after that.

```html
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
  'use strict';
  window.fx = true;

  let foo = 'bar';
  console.log(foo);
</script>
<script>
  if (typeof window.fx === 'undefined') {
    var oldScript = document.querySelector('script[type="application/javascript;version=1.7"]');
    var text = oldScript.text;
    document.body.removeChild(oldScript);

    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.text = text;
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
  }
</script>
```

The main disadvantage here is the extra HTTP request that may be incurred when referencing an external script, especially if the script is not cached. Since Firefox is the *only* browser on which you can guarantee that the script will never be requested more than once per page load, this has the potential of being incredibly wasteful on other browsers.

As an alternative, you can use feature detection as mentioned in the comments to insert the `script` element either with or without the `type` attribute rather than including it in the HTML source to start with. According to [MDN's compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility), basic support is available starting from Firefox 2.0 (in JavaScript 1.7), so you can pick pretty much any Firefox-specific feature from whichever version you wish to extend your support to.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = '"use strict"; let foo = "bar"; console.log(foo);';

try {
  document.querySelector('::-moz-selection');
  script.type = 'application/javascript;version=1.7';
} catch (e) {
  // Not Firefox, leave MIME type unchanged
}

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks. Feature detection is clearly cleaner, but still a bit hacky, and requires escaping quotes in the script, etc. Still curious if there is a native solution?

Comment: @Ben: I was using `.text` as an example since having an external script means the script needs to be hosted somewhere in order for my examples to work. If you have an external script, you don't need to escape anything; simply set the `.src` property instead.